# Celery Error: Cannot connect to Redis result backend, despite valid credentials and successful broker connection

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

I am encountering an issue with my Celery setup where I am unable to connect to the Redis result back-end. Despite providing valid credentials and successfully connecting to the broker, I receive the following error message:

`[2023-07-14 16:55:22,255: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://:**@eu1-brave-turtle-39167.upstash.io:39167//: Connection closed by server.. Trying again in 8.00 seconds... (4/100)`

I have verified that all the credentials used for the Redis result backend are correct, and the broker connection is established without any issues. However, the connection to the result backend fails consistently.

Here are the details of my setup:

```
Celery version: 5.2.3
Redis Cloud provider: Upstash Redis Horizontal
Redis URL for the result backend: redis://:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:<PORT>/0
Redis URL for the broker: redis://:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:<PORT>
Celery configuration:
```

Code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}})
# Enable debug mode
app.debug = True

# Set the Upload Folder
app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Uploads")

# Setup the Celery Config in Flask Application
app.config["UPSTASH_REDIS_URL"] = dotenv.get_key(".env", "UPSTASH_REDIS_URL")


BrokerURL = app.config["UPSTASH_REDIS_URL"]
ResultBackend = app.config["UPSTASH_REDIS_URL"]

print("Broker URL: ", BrokerURL)
print("Result Backend: ", ResultBackend)

# Initialize Celery
celery = Celery(
    app.name,
)

celery.conf.broker_url = BrokerURL
celery.conf.result_backend = f"{ResultBackend}/0"
```

---

I have already tried the following troubleshooting steps:

```
1. Double-checked the Redis URL and credentials for the result backend.

2.Verified network connectivity and ensured that there are no firewall restrictions blocking the connection.

3. Confirmed the Redis Upstash Server instance is running and accessible.

4.Tested the connection using a Redis client library, which was successful.

5. Enabled logging in Celery to check for any additional error messages.
```

Despite these efforts, I am still unable to establish a connection to the Redis result backend. What things can I try to resolve this issue?

PS: I already tried to use Redis on my local machine with WSL, all seems good, but now I have to use a Production Redis Database so I am using Upstash since it exists in Heroku Add-ons.

I have already tried the following troubleshooting steps mentioned above, and tried to use a different Redis Provider "Redis Cloud Entreprise", but still the Worker is running with the command `celery -A app.celery worker -l INFO`.

But few seconds later I get the error above.

Comment: Try running with -l DEBUG and see the values of transport and results in the logs. It shouldn't be an issue with upstash as celery uses generic redis commands for storing results

Comment: I debugged the startup of the Worker, and it's all good, but the problem consists of the Consumer, once it starts the connection, it returns a connection refused by the server.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE: SOLUTION

After hours of debugging and searching for solutions, the problem wasn't from Redis's End, or even Upstash.

I found in the Documentation of Celery that when using TLS/SSL Connection with Redis, the protocol shall change to something else.

This is my previous Environment File variable:

```
# Broker
CELERY_BROKER_URL="redis://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:<PORT>"

# Back-end
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:<PORT>/0'
```

And this is how it works correctly:

```
# Broker
CELERY_BROKER_URL="rediss://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:<PORT>?ssl_cert_reqs=required"

# Back-end
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='rediss://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:<PORT>/0?ssl_cert_reqs=required'
```

More information at [Celery's Docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#conf-redis-result-backend).

The difference is that I found Upstash using TLS/SSL to establish the Redis Connection, so the Protocol shall change from "redis" to "rediss", plus some additional URL Parameters to set it up.